# Importing SvsServiceProvider in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-snippets, vs-extensibility

I am new to Visual Studio Extensibility and am try to implement one of the Microsoft Walkthroughs from the VS 2012 SDK ([Displaying Statement Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee372314.aspx)). I am having some difficulty with one class in the walkthrough. The problem is that I get a an error that `SVsServiceProvider` is not defined. I have imported `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell`.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities


<Export(GetType(IVsTextViewCreationListener))>
<Name("token completion handler")>
<ContentType("plaintext")> <TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)>
Friend Class TestCompletionHandlerProvider
Implements IVsTextViewCreationListener

<Import()>
Friend AdapterService As IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService = Nothing
<Import()>
Friend Property CompletionBroker() As ICompletionBroker
<Import()>
Friend Property ServiceProvider() As SVsServiceProvider

Public Sub VsTextViewCreated(ByVal textViewAdapter As IVsTextView) Implements IVsTextViewCreationListener.VsTextViewCreated
    Dim textView As ITextView = AdapterService.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter)
    If textView Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim createCommandHandler As Func(Of TestCompletionCommandHandler) = Function() New TestCompletionCommandHandler(textViewAdapter, textView, Me)
    textView.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(createCommandHandler)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll is the answer. I was using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0. Thank you Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted by Simon in the comments on the original question, add a reference to:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll
```

If you are using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0.dll` then you will encounter a null `SvsServiceProvider`.